# Page reloading on Ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, accordion, reload

I have a form segmented into three divs, displayed in an an accordion style and submitted in an Ajax call, however it seems that the page is reloading because any displayed accordion divs will hide following the call. I think I have prevented the default action correctly but it seems that I am missing something.

```
//------------------ accordion -------------------------------------
$('.heading').on('click', 'img', function() {

    var x = $(this).parent().next('div');
    $(x).slideToggle(function() {
        if($(x).not(":hidden")) {
            $(this).prev().find('img').attr('src','images/triangle_red_up.jpg');
            }
        if($(x).is(":hidden")) {
                $(this).prev().find('img').attr('src','images/triangle.jpg');
                }
        });
    });

Ajax
//------------------ form submit -----------------------------------        
$('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    var datastring = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes_php/pU_6.php",
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            messages(data);
        }
        })
     })

$('input#submit').click() {
$('form').submit();
```

});

Comment: Is your `#submit` element inside the form? If not, you may need to `preventDefault` on click of that element as well.

Comment: No, it's a button element outside the form and that's why I didn't preventDefault it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('#submit').click() {
            e.preventDefault(); 
        var datastring = $('form').serialize();//if you have a form id use $('<frm id>').serialize()

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes_php/pU_6.php",
            data: datastring,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                messages(data);
            }
           });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad - had a location.reload in the messages() function.